# Express pivot table filter as what is hidden instead of what is shown?

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table, powerpivot

The following code was created by the macro recorder. It lists what should be shown.

```
With pvtSource.PivotFields("[dimCalendar].[FinancialYear].[FinancialYear]")
    .VisibleItemsList = Array("[dimCalendar].[FinancialYear].&[2014]", "[dimCalendar].[FinancialYear].&[2015]", "[dimCalendar].[FinancialYear].&[2016]")
End With
```

Is it possible to rewrite this so that it lists what should be hidden? I want to hide 2013.

The following surprisingly didn't work:

```
With pvtSource.PivotFields("[dimCalendar].[FinancialYear].[FinancialYear]")
    .HiddenItemsList = Array("[dimCalendar].[FinancialYear].&[2013]")
End With
```

> Error 1004 Application defined or object defined error

Comment: The only difference that I can see with the examples that I came across is the `&`, but as it seems to work for the visible list, I guess it should too for the hidden one... Have you tried with 2 things to hide?

Answer (score 1):

My first thought would be to enumerate all options in an array, then remove from that array the option you want to hide, and use the new, smaller array to set VisibleItemsList.

Logically equivalent if you know the items you want to remove, and probably faster/easier than fighting VBA to understand why you can't set HiddenItemsList.

My only concern would be around performance if you have a particularly large dimension. With this specific example, I wouldn't worry too much, because even a ludicrously large date dimension would have on the order of hundreds of years.